# Why common echo line between while and do create a dead while loop in bash?

Tags: bash

The while loop will execute for 3 times.

```
i=0
while [[ $i -lt 3 ]]
do
    echo "haha"
    ((i++))
done
```

Output:

```
haha
haha
haha
```

Let me add a line `echo "i am here"` between while and do.

```
i=0
while [[ $i -lt 3 ]]
echo "i am here"
do
    echo "haha"
    ((i++))
done
```

Why did it become a dead loop,never stop,output

```
i am here
haha
```

forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `--help` of bash on `while`.

```
bash.exe"-3.1$ help while
while: while COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done
     Expand and execute COMMANDS as long as the final command in the
    `while' COMMANDS has an exit status of zero.
```

The final command in `while` in your case is

```
echo "i am here"
```

It will always execute successfully, because it cannot fail.
In that case the exit status is zero - always.

Compare https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html

> For the shell’s purposes, a command which exits with a zero exit status has succeeded.

So you have programmed an endless loop.